# Draw overlapping outlined text with PIL(LOW)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to draw outlined text with PILLOW, so that the characters overlap. However, the overlapping occurs in a 'z-layer' manner, i.e. the characters are still opaque and not truly transparent.

My code is as follows:

```py
YC_CHARS = '0123456789'
YC_LENGTH = 6
YC_WIDTH = 200
YC_HEIGHT = 60
YC_BACKCOLOR = (255, 255, 255, 255)
YC_BACKCOLOR_TR = (255, 255, 255, 0)
YC_TEXTCOLOR = (0, 0, 0, 255)
YC_FONTS =  ['fonts/antquab.ttf', 'fonts/ariblk.ttf', 'fonts/arlrdbd.ttf',
             'fonts/comic.ttf', 'fonts/impact.ttf']
YC_FONTSZ = list(range(40, 51, 5))

def synth_captcha():

    def outline_text(dr, pos, text, fnt, stroke, fill):
        "Draw outline-style text"
        dr.text((pos[0]-1, pos[1]), text, font=fnt, fill=stroke)
        dr.text((pos[0]+1, pos[1]), text, font=fnt, fill=stroke)
        dr.text((pos[0], pos[1]-1), text, font=fnt, fill=stroke)
        dr.text((pos[0], pos[1]+1), text, font=fnt, fill=stroke)
        dr.text(tuple(pos), text, font=fnt, fill=fill)

    img = Image.new('RGB', (YC_WIDTH, YC_HEIGHT), color=YC_BACKCOLOR)

    digit_offset = [random.randint(1, 3), random.randint(1, 10)]
    digit_sz = [0, 0]
    digit_offset = [1, 0]

    for i in range(YC_LENGTH):

        digit = random.choice(YC_CHARS)        
        font = ImageFont.truetype(random.choice(YC_FONTS), random.choice(YC_FONTSZ))
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img, mode='RGBA')

        digit_offset[0] += digit_sz[0] + random.randint(-digit_sz[0]//1.5, 0)
        digit_sz = draw.textsize(digit, font=font)
        digit_offset[1] = random.randint(1, max(2, YC_HEIGHT - digit_sz[1] - 2))
        outline_text(draw, digit_offset, digit, font, YC_TEXTCOLOR, YC_BACKCOLOR_TR)

    img.save('img.png')
```

This code produces the following image:
[image: actual image]

But I need to have it as follows:
[image: expected image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to [use `Image.alpha_composite`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/ImageDraw.html#example-draw-partial-opacity-text) to draw things with partial opacity.

Example code:

```
def synth_captcha():

    def outline_text(dr, pos, text, fnt, stroke, fill):
        "Draw outline-style text"
        dr.text((pos[0]-1, pos[1]), text, font=fnt, fill=stroke)
        dr.text((pos[0]+1, pos[1]), text, font=fnt, fill=stroke)
        dr.text((pos[0], pos[1]-1), text, font=fnt, fill=stroke)
        dr.text((pos[0], pos[1]+1), text, font=fnt, fill=stroke)
        dr.text(tuple(pos), text, font=fnt, fill=fill)

    img = Image.new('RGBA', (YC_WIDTH, YC_HEIGHT), color=YC_BACKCOLOR)

    digit_offset = [random.randint(1, 3), random.randint(1, 10)]
    digit_sz = [0, 0]
    digit_offset = [1, 0]

    for i in range(YC_LENGTH):

        digit = random.choice(YC_CHARS)        
        font = ImageFont.truetype(random.choice(YC_FONTS), random.choice(YC_FONTSZ))
        txt = Image.new('RGBA', img.size, YC_BACKCOLOR_TR)
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(txt)

        digit_offset[0] += digit_sz[0] + random.randint(-digit_sz[0]//1.5, 0)
        digit_sz = draw.textsize(digit, font=font)
        digit_offset[1] = random.randint(1, max(2, YC_HEIGHT - digit_sz[1] - 2))
        outline_text(draw, digit_offset, digit, font, YC_TEXTCOLOR, YC_BACKCOLOR_TR)

        img = Image.alpha_composite(img, txt)

    return img
```

Edit: Changing `YC_BACKCOLOR_TR` to `(0, 0, 0, 0)` would give more solid-looking strokes. I'm not sure why, but it probably have something to do with the way `dr.text` handles transparency at the border of characters.

My guess is that it simply blends the RGBA value as a 4d vector, so for a pixel that is normally drawn at 50% opacity, blending `(0, 0, 0, 255)` with `(255, 255, 255, 0)` yields `(128, 128, 128, 128)`. When that pixel is alpha-composited onto the white background, it becomes `(192, 192, 192, 255)`, which is a lighter gray than it should be. I think in your case, working only on the alpha map (i.e. `YC_BACKCOLOR_TR = (0, 0, 0, 0)`) is a reasonable approach, but I'm curious if there is a better or conceptually simpler way to do this.